# pre_get_posts and set

Tags: meta-query, pre-get-posts

I have some functions into my `pre_get_posts` filter. So, the problem is that when I set a `meta_query`, **all the menus disappear from the page**.

```
function propersearchfilter($query) {
    $taxarray = array();
    $metaarray = array();

    array_push($metaarray , array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-market',
        'value' => 'forsell',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ));

    $query->set('meta_query', $metaarray);
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'propersearchfilter', 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`pre_get_posts` triggers for *every* query (front and admin side). It also triggers when querying nav-menu items (which is what is happening here).

Most of the time you only want to filter particular queries - so you need to check if that query is one you wish to modify.

Usually - and I think your example might be one - you only want to modify the 'main query'.

```
function wpse72969_pre_get_posts( $query) {
    //If its not the 'main query' don't do antying.
    if( !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    return $query; 
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse72969_pre_get_posts');
```

More generally [all the conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) are available to you (**Note:** you want want to use the *methods* and not the functions: e.g. `$query->is_search()` as opposed to `is_search()`.

You can even set custom variables to identify queries.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `pre_get_posts` fires on every single instance of `WP_Query`.  Posts get used for a lot of things in WordPress, including nav menus.

If you want to only modify the main query (the "loop") you can test for `is_main_query`.

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse72969_modify_q');
function wpse72969_modify_q($q)
{
    if(!$q->is_main_query())
        return;

    // any calls to `set` here will modify ONLY the main query
}
```

You can also use any of the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) as well:

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse72969_modify_q2');
function wpse72969_modify_q2($q)
{
    if(!$q->is_main_query() || !$q->is_search())
        return;

    // any calls to `set` here will modify ONLY 
    // the main query on search pages.
}
```